# Difference between declaring and directly attributing

Tags: java, performance

This is a quite simple doubt of mine. Let's say I have a constant `final String CUSTOMER = "Customer Name"`. Somewhere in my code I'd like to call this String.

I can do `String cust = CUSTOMER` or, directly, `String cust = "Customer Name"`.

In terms of memory and performance does it make any difference?

Comment: Constants have more to do with clean, well-factored code, and less to do with technical efficiency. This said, the worst case scenario is to declare a constant and then not bother using it.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise there will be no difference as in both cases only references (think pointers) to objects are assigned. In the most cases string constants in the code is a bad style, so better take them out to a final static field.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of memory if you create a variable, you will spend more by assigning it. For the variable will have to be allocated in memory.

Otherwise, you are only directly assigning a static message. Which consumed less memory, although today, doesn't make much difference only in applications that really need to use very little memory.

Note: Sorry, for bad english.

Comment: You're right in general, but wrong in thus case (string constants are pre-created).